# Security for FTP connection between same servers

Tags: php, ftp

In PHP, I am accessing another user's files using FTP on the same server. In this case, do I need to use secure FTP or is it ok to have normal FTP as both source and destination are on same server?

Thanks.

Comment: Voting: Should be Closed -> Off Topic > Other Site

Comment: See at [security.se]: [Is there a benefit to having SSL connections on localhost?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48892/is-there-a-benefit-to-having-ssl-connections-on-localhost).